# Group by with latest record on join query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Here is my table `deals_transaction_status_log`  with the following fields

id,user_id,deal_transaction_id,transaction_status_id in which i want to fetch the records with group by on `transaction_id` with latest record on(max `id`).

This table also join some another tables to get some other data.

Here is my query

```
SELECT dtsl.id ,dtsl.deal_transaction_id,dts.id as statusId
    FROM deals_transaction_status_log as dtsl
    JOIN deals_transactions as dt ON dt.id=dtsl.deal_transaction_id AND dt.visitor_id=140
    JOIN DEALS as d ON d.idDeal=dt.deal_id 
    JOIN USER as u ON d.userId=u.idUser
    JOIN deals_transaction_status as dts ON dts.id=dtsl.transaction_status_id
    WHERE dtsl.user_id!=140 AND dtsl.transaction_status_id=14  AND  dtsl.id IN (
                SELECT MAX(dtsl.id)
                FROM deals_transaction_status_log as dtsl
                GROUP BY  dtsl.deal_transaction_id
            ) GROUP BY dtsl.deal_transaction_id
```

This works fine however it returns only one record even if i have more than one record with same `deal_transaction_id`

for eg:

### Sample Input

```
id user_id deal_transaction_id transaction_status_id
1  4        2                  14
2  4        2                  14
3  5        3                  14
4  5        3                  14
```

### Result

```
id statusId deal_transaction_id

3   14      3
```

### Expected result

```
id statusId deal_transaction_id

2   14      2
4   14      3
```

**UPDATE**

I just tried  fa06 answer without any join

```
SELECT dtsl.id,dtsl.deal_transaction_id,dtsl.transaction_status_id FROM deals_transaction_status_log as dtsl
WHERE dtsl.id IN (
                SELECT MAX(id)
                FROM deals_transaction_status_log as b where dtsl.transaction_status_id=b.transaction_status_id)
                AND dtsl.transaction_status_id=14
GROUP BY dtsl.deal_transaction_id
```

But still i am getting only one row

Comment: A group by without any aggregate functions is unlikely to be useful

Comment: @P.Salmon i didn't get you

Comment: The feelings mutual, your query uses 5 tables and you have provided sample input for 1 can you either provide sample data for all tables or cut your query down to use only the sample data you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery

```
SELECT dtsl.id ,dtsl.deal_transaction_id,dts.id as statusId
    FROM deals_transaction_status_log as dtsl
    JOIN deals_transactions as dt ON dt.id=dtsl.deal_transaction_id AND dt.visitor_id=140
    JOIN DEALS as d ON d.idDeal=dt.deal_id 
    JOIN USER as u ON d.userId=u.idUser
    JOIN deals_transaction_status as dts ON dts.id=dtsl.transaction_status_id
    WHERE dtsl.user_id!=140 AND dtsl.transaction_status_id=14  AND  dtsl.id IN (
                SELECT MAX(id)
                FROM deals_transaction_status_log as b where dtsl.deal_transaction_id=b.deal_transaction_id)
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error `your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b where dtsl.transaction_status_id=b.transaction_status_id
            ) GROUP ' at line 11`

Comment: Now i am getting two rows but the `id`s  for each row are the first one not the latest `id`

Comment: now it returns only one row as i described in my question:(

Comment: MySql Ver 5.7.25